# AngluarJS Reuse Functions (Where do i put them)

Tags: angularjs

Lets say i want to reuse a function in angularjs that returns a specific value  but i want to call it in other parts controllers of the app so i don't rewrite it in other places (dry) , where would i put that function in an angularjs app? Would i make a service of factory for this?

Say i have two controllers and in those two controllers i want to call function `foo()` that returns a certain number when i pass a variable through it. Where would i put function `foo()` in my angular structure?

Comment: Tell us which version of angular you are using so we people can tailor their answers.

Comment: if it is a hard coded one, then try adding constant

Comment: Im using AngularJS 1.6.4.

Comment: And the hardcoded answer changes if i pass a variable through it sorry *its not hardcoded*

Comment: See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating Services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services#creating-services).

Answer (score 0):

With Angular 1.x you would need to create a `service` to make something reusable or like a utility. You can inject this to the controller you want to in a similar fashion as you would do for a `http` service for example. Taken from the [AngularJS website](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services), a service is defined as -

> AngularJS services are substitutable objects that are wired together
>   using dependency injection (DI). You can use services to organize and
>   share code across your app.

You can find a very simple servic being implemented here - [an example by w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_services_custom)

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS has three very similar concepts services, factories, and providers. Each one can be used to expose apis using DRY patterns. Most often it's a matter of preference between using a service, factory, or provider. I tend to prefer using factories.

Here is a jsfiddle of a simple example where I use a factory to expose an api: https://jsfiddle.net/kaxtxL1h/

```
var app = angular
  .module("app", [])
  .factory("myapi", function() {
    var api = {
      foo: function (bar) {
        return bar + "_baz"
      }
    };
    //now api is exposed to whoever injects myapi
    return api;
  })
  .controller("ControllerOne", function($scope, myapi) {
    $scope.value = myapi.foo("one");
  })
  .controller("ControllerTwo", function($scope, myapi) {
    $scope.value = myapi.foo("two");
  });
```

Here is a good reference for understanding the similarities and differences between services, factories, and providers: [AngularJS: Service vs provider vs factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angularjs-service-vs-provider-vs-factory)